# Associate a property with a class in OWL/Protege

Tags: owl, protege

Consider this scenario:

- There are employers and employees. I model this with a class `Employer` and a class `Employee`.
- Then I create an object property `hasEmployer` with inverse `hasEmployee`.
- Now I also create a class called `EmploymentContract`.

I want to be able to say that for every `hasEmployer` property, and its inverse, there must exist an `EmploymentContract` associated with that relation.

So basically I want something called `hasEmploymentContract` which is a property with domain `hasEmployer` (an object property) and range `EmploymentContract` (a class).

Is this possible in OWL? Am I thinking about the problem wrong maybe?

If possible, an implementation using Protege Ontology Editor would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *""hasEmploymentContract" which is a property with domain "hasEmployer" (an object property) and range "EmploymentContract" (a class)"* - that is simply defining domain and range of an object property in OWL, why should it not be possible? Open the ontology in Protege, click on the object property and just set domain and range. Did you try this or what does not work?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried. The only options for domain are classes. I can't input a property as a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n-ary relations are one way to deal with this. Another is through property chaining. For this I will assume the diagram as given below. Here the chained properties `providesEmploymentContract, hasEmployeeAsParticipant` represent the property `hasEmployee`. This means an `Employer` that is in a `providesEmploymentContract` relation with an `EmploymentContract` where the `EmploymentContract` is in a `hasEmployeeAsParticipant` with an `Employee`, is an `Employer` that is in a `hasEmployee` relation with the `Employee`.

[image]

Similar relations can be set up for `hasEmployer` based on the diagram. In Protege this can be represented as follows:

```
Class: Employee    
Class: Employer    
Class: EmploymentContract

ObjectProperty: providesEmploymentContract
  Domain: Employer
  Range: EmploymentContract

ObjectProperty: agreesToEmploymentContract
  Domain:Employee
  Range: EmploymentContract

ObjectProperty: hasEmployerAsParticipant
  Domain: EmploymentContract
  Range: Employer

ObjectProperty: hasEmployeeAsParticipant
  Domain: EmploymentContract
  Range: Employee

ObjectProperty: hasEmployee
  SubPropertyChain: providesEmploymentContract o hasEmployeeAsParticipant
  Domain: Employer
  Range:  Employee
  InverseOf: hasEmployer

ObjectProperty: hasEmployer
  SubPropertyChain: agreesToEmploymentContract o hasEmployerAsParticipant
  Domain: Employee
  Range: Employer
  InverseOf: hasEmployee
```

Answer (score -1):

Notwithstanding the snarky comments indicating that I was being stupid, it appears that it is indeed not possible to implement this logic directly. The W3C working group has identified this shortcoming released a "Working Group Note" on design patterns for achieving this behavior through other means, which I eventually found. In fact an example in the head of the document is almost identical to my question:

*Another example is representing relations among multiple individuals, such as a buyer, a seller, and an object that was bought when describing a purchase of a book.*

For anyone else interested, that document can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/